# Share ArcGIS Desktop and Pro 2.7 with FME Desktop

Tags: arcgis-desktop, arcgis-pro, enterprise-geodatabase, fme-form

Actually, I use FME 2020.2, ArcGIS Desktop and ArcGIS Pro on the same computer.
FME uses the ArcGIS products to read/write the data in a Enterprise geodatabase.

Since I installed ArcGIS Pro, I cannot read/write SDE anymore

C:\Users\Stanusjl\AppData\Roaming\Esri\ArcGISPro\Favorites

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In fact, ArcGIS 2.7 Pro is not compatible with 2020.x but with 2021.x

> ### FME 2021.0.0.0 b21225 20201106
>
> Teradata JDBC: Avoided loading all drivers in classpath by loading driver by class name [FMEENGINE-67216]
>
> Python: Added Python support for ArcGIS Pro 2.7 [FMEENGINE-66865]
>
> SweptSolidBuilder: Fixed crash caused by zero or nan fixed reference
> vectors [FMEENGINE-67628]